# Generic with List

Tags: java

I have a generic method that takes List (extend Person) and should result a new List S(extend Student).
The teacher said I am not allowed to cast (S)t as I did in my code.

Student class extends Person class

```
// Main
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
people.add(new Person());
people.add(new Student());
List<Person> students = new ArrayList<>(getStudent(people));
System.out.println(students);



// Method Below Main
public static <T extends Person, S extends Student> List<S> 
getStudent2(List<T> list) {
    List<S> students = new ArrayList<>();
    for (T t : list) {
        if (t instanceof Student)
        students.add((S) t);
    }
    return students;
}
```

Is there a better way to get a generic List of Superclass Person and result in a new list of its subClass Student?

Comment: How do you call this method?

Comment: @akuzminykh I added...

Comment: did the teacher meant you must use `(Student)`  instead of  `(S)`?

Comment: @user15244370 I do not think so anyway it does not work with Student because we talk about generic here

Comment: Why are you using `S extends Student`? Why not return `List<Student>`?

Comment: well, maybe you should have asked the teacher... (sorry if I wasn't direct enough)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the problem with your code:

```
static class Student extends Person {
}

static class Sophomore extends Student {
}

static class Person {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
    people.add(new Student());
    people.add(new Sophomore());
    people.add(new Person());

    List<Sophomore> sophomores = getStudent2(people);
    System.out.println(sophomores);
}
```

sophomores array has a Student in it, who is not a Sophomore.

You can change it by reifying the `S` generic like so:

```
public static <T extends Person, S extends Student> List<S> getStudent3(List<T> list, Class<S> targetClass) {
    List<S> students = new ArrayList<>();
    for (T t : list) {
        if (targetClass.isInstance(t))
            students.add((S) t);
    }
    return students;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
    people.add(new Student());
    people.add(new Sophomore());
    people.add(new Person());

    List<Sophomore> sophomores = getStudent3(people, Sophomore.class);
    System.out.println(sophomores);
}
```

Comment: You still using (S)

Comment: @UIUX I'm using (S) but the cast is now legal because we assert that `targetClass.isAssignableFrom(t.getClass())`. There is no way that we are casting something to `S` that is not actually `S`, like your original example does.

Comment: maybe `targetClass.cast(t)` instead of `(S)`? (and `isInstance(t)` instead of `isAssignableFrom`?)

Comment: @UIUX Your question said *"I am not allowed to cast (S)t as I did in my code"*, which is different from simply not being allowed to cast to S. The cast in this answer is *not like* the cast in your code, because this cast is safe whereas your cast is unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what exactly you assignment is or your return type `(List<Student> vs List<Person>)`.  But you can do the following:

```
List<? extends Person> students = getStudent(people);
```

By making the following changes:

- return type is `List<? extends T>`
- put the Students in a `List<T>`
- remove the type designation `S extends Student`

```
public static <T extends Person> List<? extends T> 
getStudent(List<T> list) {
    List<T> students = new ArrayList<>();
    for (T t : list) {
        if (t instanceof Student)
            students.add(t);
    }
    return students;
}
```

The problem here is that if you want to use the list as a list of `Student` along with the methods of the Student class then you must cast `Person to Student` where appropriate.  Otherwise you will need to return a bounded list which will be subject to the `get and put principal` of [contravariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) data structures like Lists.

Comment: I see, but what is the point than of the  S extends Student in the method?

Comment: Sorry about that.  It was accidentally left in from  your original post.  You don't need it.  I modified my answer.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

I think the best way, is using abstraction concept,

here the example, hope its help

```
public static <T extends Person, S extends Student> List<People> getStudent2(List<T> list) {
    List<People> students = new ArrayList<>();
    for (People t : list){
        if (t instanceof Student){
            students.add(t);
        }
    }

    return students;
}

static class Person implements People {

}

static class Student implements People {

}

interface People {

}
```

//main

```
List<People> people = new ArrayList<>();
people.add(new Person());
people.add(new Student());
List<People> students = new ArrayList<>(getStudent(people));
System.out.println(students);
```